# WPF Listbox Animation on item selected

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'd like to achive this on my wpf app :

[image]

when the item is selected, the item moove up and let space for items in this item

and when another item is selected chapter one for example : chapter 2 and 3 shlould be sticked together and chapter one moove up to let space for items in champter one.

edit :

i tried this :

```
 <ListBox x:Name="liste" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="274" Margin="10,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="774">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Expanded="exp_Expanded" x:Name="exp"></Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="transform"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Selected">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                        
                                        <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:1" Value="0,0,0,100" />
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>


                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     
    </ListBox>
```

Could you help me to make this animation please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Create `ListboxItem` template

#### 2. Set the height of the area to be shown when selected to zero.

#### 3. Adjust the height value through `DoubleAnimation` in the trigger.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="header">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Padding="5 10 0 10"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Grid x:Name="items" Grid.Row="1" Height="0" Opacity="0">
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding SubItem}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="items" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="30"  BeginTime="0:0:0.2" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="items" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"  BeginTime="0:0:0.2" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="items" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="0"  Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="items" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SkyBlue"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="header" Property="Background" Value="#132E47"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]

#### I put the sample code on github.

[here](https://github.com/devncore/community/tree/main/stackoverflow/answers/listboxitem-animation-example)

Comment: Thanks you it works very well and it's done what i wanted. Is there a way to change `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="30"` the value 30 dynamically in code ?

Comment: The storyboard must have the correct scenario. And since the first height value is '0', the dynamic height value cannot be found from the `Storyboard` point of view.